# Why razor pages don`t set a get param?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

When i try get my Razor page with `/?page=1` params, i expect that my `page` param will be a 1, but it a still 0. Why is it not being read from the url and what can i do about it?

```
public async Task OnGetAsync(string[] tags, int page)
{
    _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, $"New index request, page {page}");
    var find = new Api.FindApi(cs);
    posts = await find.Find(tags, Page*Constants.POST_PER_PAGE);
}
```

I also tried this, but it still not working

```
[FromQuery(Name = "page")]
public int Page{get;private set;}
```

Comment: You cannot use `page` as a route value in Razor Pages because it is a reserved word. Looks like that exemption also applies to query string keys.

Comment: @MikeBrind yes, you are right, https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/wiki/MVC-Reserved-Keywords says that the `page` will not be bound correctly, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[FromQuery(Name ="page")]` befor your parameter to solve this problem like this:

```
public async Task OnGetAsync([FromQuery(Name ="page")]int page, string[] tags)
{
    //Your Code
}
```

Comment: since the parameter and argument names are the same you can get away with just `[FromQuery]int page, ...`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `FromQuery` attribute, in a Razor page you should probably be using the `BindProperty` attribute on those query param properties.

You should also remove the `private` modifier on the setter for `Page`

```cs
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public int Page { get; set; }
```

Comment: That won't work for a property named `Page` because it's a reserved word.